# R, ggplot: "Discretizing" continous vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

To make the colour-gradients shape more obvious when plotting the effect of a "continous:continous"-interaction as a heatmap, I'm looking for a way to make the z-values (defining the colour-fill) discrete.

At the moment I'm using `base::cut()` with some rather dirty transformations afterwards to get it done.

Does anyone know of a better way to get the same result?

```
library(tidyverse)

surface <-   
  volcano %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "y") %>%
  gather("x", "z", -y) %>%
  mutate(y = y %>% 
           as.integer(),
         x = x %>% 
           str_replace("V", "") %>% 
           as.integer())

surface %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) +
  geom_bin2d(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu")
```

What I get by default:

[image]

```
surface %>% 
  mutate(z = z %>% 
           cut(10, include.lowest=TRUE) %>%
           fct_relabel(. %>% str_replace_all("\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]","")) %>%
           str_split(",") %>%
           map(. %>% as.double() %>% mean()) %>%
           unlist()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) +
  geom_bin2d(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu")
```

What I want:

[image]

**EDIT:**

`unlist()` removed by using `map_dbl()` and discretized colourbar in the legend

```
surface %>% 
  mutate(z = z %>% 
           cut(10, include.lowest=TRUE) %>%
           fct_relabel(. %>% str_replace_all("\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]","")) %>%
           str_split(",") %>%
           map_dbl(. %>% as.double() %>% mean())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) +
  geom_bin2d(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu",
                       guide=guide_colourbar(nbin=10, raster=FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Does the `bins` argument help you? See examples in `geom_bin2d`.

Comment: This would change the resolution of x and y. I'd need a `bins` argument in `scale_fill_distiller()`

Answer (score 0):

The following replaces 4 lines of code by just one. Does it qualify as better?

```
surface %>% 
  mutate(z = z %>% 
           cut(10, include.lowest=TRUE) %>%
           map(. %>% as.integer()) %>%
           unlist()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) +
  geom_bin2d(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu")
```

As you can see, it's basically the same algorithm.

Comment: This way the values of z get transformed to `1:10`.

Comment: @rackelhahn69 Yes, but the result is same plot, with a different scale. You are not interested in transforming the data.frame, am I right?

Comment: I'd still like the colourbar in the legend to be annotated by the original values of $z$